# How to load layers from postgis to dotspatial or sharemap viewer

Tags: postgis, c#, postgresql, layers

I want to develop a PostGIS viewer for PostgreSQL (with SQL query editor) to visualize PostGIS layers.

Which spatial library (.net C# supported) do I have to use?

Answer (score 4):

Two thoughts:

1. Why not just use QGIS?  It performs a lot more functions than what you are looking for, but is ready to go 'out of the box'.
2. [This is a plugin](http://geotux.tuxfamily.org/index.php/en/component/k2/item/293-consola-sql-para-plugin-pgadmin-postgis-viewer) for PGAdmin3 that lets you view postgis table geometries as images (maps).

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do your personal C# development, I would suggest you to adopt PostGIS/PostgreSQL + SharpMap. The SharpMap can be used as front-end to visualise map layers, and the PostGIS can be used as data storage. The SharpMap has provided data provider for PostGIS so you can read layer data stored in PostGIS directly and display on the Map control in SharpMap.